# It is possible to create splash screen (page loading) in Dart?

Tags: dom, dart, pageload

Hello all (but especially to Gunter :)). Is it possible to create splash screen (loading page) using Dart? As far as I know, at the moment Dart can be invoked only after DOM content is loaded.

I want to implement simple example:

1. While page is loading show exclamation mart (!) on blank screen.
2. After page have loaded - show the page document itself.

Comment: Do you really need Dart for this? You can just add it statically to your HTML page and then remove it when Dart is ready.

Comment: Hey..good point! I've never done it before (nor using Dart or JS), but your suggestion looks ingeniously simple.